# DrawerLayout in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, uielementcollection

I added a **DrawerLayout** Nuget package to my Windows Phone 8.1 WINRT App. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DrawerLayout/

Tutorial:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-81-Now-its-b63049f9

So after the reference is added, I wrote code. Clicking on the humberger button opens the drawer/list and clicking it back again closes this again. It works fine but, sometimes the app crashes. I tried using breakpoint on every statement but it doesn't help. So I got the source code of this DrawerLayout (DrawerLayout.cs). In this cs file there is:

```
 try
            {
                _mainFragment = Children.OfType<Grid>().FirstOrDefault();
                _listFragment = Children.OfType<Grid>().ElementAt(1);
            }
```

But it says **UIElementCollection** does not contain any definition for **OfType**.
I checked MSDN Documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

and it shows **OfType** in extension methods. How to use this OfType? Any replacement?

**Full Code of DrawerLayout.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;

namespace DrawerLayout
{
    public class DrawerLayout : Grid
    {
        #region Globals and events

        private readonly PropertyPath _translatePath = new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)");
        private readonly PropertyPath _colorPath = new PropertyPath("(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");

        private readonly TranslateTransform _listFragmentTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        private readonly TranslateTransform _deltaTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        private const int MaxAlpha = 100;

        public delegate void DrawerEventHandler(object sender);
        public event DrawerEventHandler DrawerOpened;
        public event DrawerEventHandler DrawerClosed;

        private Storyboard _fadeInStoryboard;
        private Storyboard _fadeOutStoryboard;
        private Grid _listFragment;
        private Grid _mainFragment;
        private Grid _shadowFragment;

        #endregion

        #region Dependency Properties

        public bool IsDrawerOpen
        {
             get { return (bool)GetValue(IsDrawerOpenProperty); }
             set { SetValue(IsDrawerOpenProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDrawerOpenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsDrawerOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(DrawerLayout), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        private PropertyPath TranslatePath
        {
            get { return _translatePath; }
        }
        private PropertyPath ColorPath
        {
            get { return _colorPath; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public DrawerLayout()
        {
            IsDrawerOpen = false;
        }

        public void InitializeDrawerLayout()
        {
            if (Children == null) return;
            if (Children.Count < 2) return;

            try
            {
                _mainFragment = Children.OfType<Grid>().FirstOrDefault();
                _listFragment = Children.OfType<Grid>().ElementAt(1);
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }

            if (_mainFragment == null || _listFragment == null) return;

            _mainFragment.Name = "_mainFragment";
            _listFragment.Name = "_listFragment";

            // _mainFragment
            _mainFragment.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            _mainFragment.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
            if (_mainFragment.Background == null) _mainFragment.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));

            // Render transform _listFragment
            _listFragment.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            _listFragment.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
            _listFragment.Width = (Window.Current.Bounds.Width/3)*2;
            if (_listFragment.Background == null) _listFragment.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));

            var animatedTranslateTransform = new TranslateTransform {X = -_listFragment.Width, Y = 0};

            _listFragment.RenderTransform = animatedTranslateTransform;
            _listFragment.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

            _listFragment.UpdateLayout();

            // Create a shadow element
            _shadowFragment = new Grid
            {
                Name = "_shadowFragment",
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255)),
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
                Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
            };
            _shadowFragment.Tapped += shadowFragment_Tapped;
            _shadowFragment.IsHitTestVisible = false;

            // Set ZIndexes
            Canvas.SetZIndex(_shadowFragment, 50);
            Canvas.SetZIndex(_listFragment, 51);
            Children.Add(_shadowFragment);

            // Create a new fadeIn animation storyboard
            _fadeInStoryboard = new Storyboard();

            // New double animation
            var doubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation {Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200)), To = 0};

            Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation1, _listFragment);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation1, TranslatePath.Path);
            _fadeInStoryboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation1);

            // New color animation for _shadowFragment
            var colorAnimation1 = new ColorAnimation
            {
                Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200)),
                To = Color.FromArgb(190, 0, 0, 0)
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(colorAnimation1, _shadowFragment);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorAnimation1,ColorPath.Path);
            _fadeInStoryboard.Children.Add(colorAnimation1);

            // Create a new fadeOut animation storyboard
            _fadeOutStoryboard = new Storyboard();

            // New double animation
            var doubleAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200)),
                To = -_listFragment.Width
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation2, _listFragment);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation2, TranslatePath.Path);
            _fadeOutStoryboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation2);

            // New color animation for _shadowFragment
            var colorAnimation2 = new ColorAnimation
            {
                Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200)),
                To = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(colorAnimation2, _shadowFragment);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorAnimation2, ColorPath.Path);
            _fadeOutStoryboard.Children.Add(colorAnimation2);

            _mainFragment.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;
            _mainFragment.ManipulationStarted += mainFragment_ManipulationStarted;

            _listFragment.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;
            _listFragment.ManipulationStarted += listFragment_ManipulationStarted;

        }
        public void OpenDrawer()
        {
            if (_fadeInStoryboard == null || _mainFragment == null || _listFragment == null) return;
            _shadowFragment.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            _shadowFragment.IsHitTestVisible = true;
            _shadowFragment.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(MaxAlpha, 0, 0, 0));
            _fadeInStoryboard.Begin();
            IsDrawerOpen = true;

            if (DrawerOpened != null)
                DrawerOpened(this);
        }
        public void CloseDrawer()
        {
            if (_fadeOutStoryboard == null || _mainFragment == null || _listFragment == null) return;
            _fadeOutStoryboard.Begin();
            _fadeOutStoryboard.Completed += fadeOutStoryboard_Completed;
            IsDrawerOpen = false;

            if (DrawerClosed != null)
                DrawerClosed(this);
        }
        private void shadowFragment_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var shadow = new Storyboard();

            var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200)),
                To = -_listFragment.Width
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, _listFragment);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, TranslatePath.Path);
            shadow.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);

            var colorAnimation = new ColorAnimation
            {
                Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200)),
                To = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(colorAnimation, _shadowFragment);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorAnimation, ColorPath.Path);
            shadow.Children.Add(colorAnimation);

            shadow.Completed += shadow_Completed;
            shadow.Begin();
        }
        private void shadow_Completed(object sender, object e)
        {
            _shadowFragment.IsHitTestVisible = false;
            _shadowFragment.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            this.IsDrawerOpen = false;

            // raise close event
            if (DrawerClosed != null) DrawerClosed(this);
        }
        private void fadeOutStoryboard_Completed(object sender, object e)
        {
            _shadowFragment.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
            _shadowFragment.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            if (DrawerClosed != null) DrawerClosed(this);
        }
        private void MoveListFragment(double left, Color color)
        {
            var s = new Storyboard();

            var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200)),
                To = left
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, _listFragment);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, TranslatePath.Path);
            s.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);

            var colorAnimation = new ColorAnimation { Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200)), To = color };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(colorAnimation, _shadowFragment);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorAnimation, ColorPath.Path);
            s.Children.Add(colorAnimation);

            s.Begin();
        }
        private void MoveShadowFragment(double left)
        {
            // Show shadow fragment
            _shadowFragment.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
            _shadowFragment.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            // Set bg color based on current _listFragment position.
            var maxLeft = _listFragment.ActualWidth;
            var currentLeft = maxLeft - left;

            var temp = Convert.ToInt32((currentLeft / maxLeft) * MaxAlpha);

            // Limit temp variable to 190 to avoid OverflowException
            if (temp > MaxAlpha) temp = MaxAlpha;

            byte alphaColorIndex;
            try
            {
                alphaColorIndex = Convert.ToByte(MaxAlpha - temp);
            }
            catch
            {
                alphaColorIndex = 0;
            }

            _shadowFragment.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(alphaColorIndex, 0, 0, 0));
        }

        #endregion

        #region List Fragment manipulation events

        private void listFragment_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var listWidth = _listFragment.Width;
            if (!(e.Position.X >= listWidth - 100) || !(e.Position.X < listWidth)) return;
            _listFragment.ManipulationDelta += listFragment_ManipulationDelta;
            _listFragment.ManipulationCompleted += listFragment_ManipulationCompleted;
        }
        private void listFragment_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(e.Cumulative.Translation.X) < 0) return;
            if (e.Cumulative.Translation.X <= -_listFragment.Width || e.Cumulative.Translation.X > 0)
            {
                listFragment_ManipulationCompleted(this, null);
                return;
            }

            _listFragmentTransform.X = e.Cumulative.Translation.X;
            _listFragment.RenderTransform = _listFragmentTransform;
            MoveShadowFragment(e.Cumulative.Translation.X + _listFragment.Width);
        }
        private void listFragment_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get left of _listFragment
            var transform = (TranslateTransform)_listFragment.RenderTransform;
            if (transform == null) return;
            var left = transform.X;

            // Set snap divider to 1/3 of _mainFragment width
            var snapLimit = _mainFragment.ActualWidth / 3;

            // Get init position of _listFragment
            const int initialPosition = 0;

            // If current left coordinate is smaller than snap limit, close drawer
            if (Math.Abs(initialPosition - left) > snapLimit)
            {
                MoveListFragment(-_listFragment.Width, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
                _shadowFragment.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                _shadowFragment.IsHitTestVisible = false;

                _listFragment.ManipulationDelta -= listFragment_ManipulationDelta;
                _listFragment.ManipulationCompleted -= listFragment_ManipulationCompleted;
                IsDrawerOpen = false;

                // raise DrawerClosed event
                if (DrawerClosed != null) DrawerClosed(this);
            }
            // else open drawer
            else if (Math.Abs(initialPosition - left) < snapLimit)
            {
                // move drawer to zero
                MoveListFragment(0, Color.FromArgb(190, 0, 0, 0));
                _shadowFragment.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                _shadowFragment.IsHitTestVisible = true;
                _listFragment.ManipulationDelta -= listFragment_ManipulationDelta;
                _listFragment.ManipulationCompleted -= listFragment_ManipulationCompleted;
                IsDrawerOpen = true;

                // raise Drawer_Open event
                if (DrawerOpened != null) DrawerOpened(this);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Main fragment manipulation events

        private void mainFragment_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // If the user has the first touch on the left side of canvas, that means he's trying to swipe the drawer
            if (!(e.Position.X <= 40)) return;

            // Manipulation can be allowed
            _mainFragment.ManipulationDelta += mainFragment_ManipulationDelta;
            _mainFragment.ManipulationCompleted += mainFragment_ManipulationCompleted;
        }
        private void mainFragment_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(e.Cumulative.Translation.X) < 0) return;
            if (e.Cumulative.Translation.X >= _listFragment.Width)
            {
                mainFragment_ManipulationCompleted(this, null);
                return;
            }

            _deltaTransform.X = -_listFragment.Width + e.Cumulative.Translation.X;
            _listFragment.RenderTransform = _deltaTransform;
            MoveShadowFragment(e.Cumulative.Translation.X);
        }
        private void mainFragment_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get left of _listFragment
            var transform = (TranslateTransform)_listFragment.RenderTransform;
            if (transform == null) return;
            var left = transform.X;

            // Set snap divider to 1/3 of _mainFragment width
            var snapLimit = _mainFragment.ActualWidth / 3;

            // Get init position of _listFragment
            var initialPosition = -_listFragment.Width;

            // If current left coordinate is smaller than snap limit, close drawer
            if (Math.Abs(initialPosition - left) < snapLimit)
            {
                MoveListFragment(initialPosition, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
                _shadowFragment.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                _shadowFragment.IsHitTestVisible = false;

                _mainFragment.ManipulationDelta -= mainFragment_ManipulationDelta;
                _mainFragment.ManipulationCompleted -= mainFragment_ManipulationCompleted;
                IsDrawerOpen = false;

                // raise DrawerClosed event
                if (DrawerClosed != null) DrawerClosed(this);
            }
            // else open drawer
            else if (Math.Abs(initialPosition - left) > snapLimit)
            {
                // move drawer to zero
                MoveListFragment(0, Color.FromArgb(190, 0, 0, 0));
                _shadowFragment.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                _shadowFragment.IsHitTestVisible = true;
                _mainFragment.ManipulationDelta -= mainFragment_ManipulationDelta;
                _mainFragment.ManipulationCompleted -= mainFragment_ManipulationCompleted;
                IsDrawerOpen = true;

                // raise DrawerClosed event
                if (DrawerOpened != null) DrawerOpened(this);
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

**Call InitializeDrawerLayout:**

```
public PageConstructor()
            {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += PageConstructor_Loaded;
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;

            }

            void PageConstructor_Loaded()
            {
            InitializeDrawer();

            }

             private void InitializeDrawer()
        {
            DrawerLayout.InitializeDrawerLayout();

            //string[] menuItems = new string[5] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5" };
            //ListMenuItems.ItemsSource = menuItems.ToList();
            ListPickerDataClassObject.ListPicker_DrawerListPicker_UserRegistrationPage();
            ListMenuItems.ItemsSource = ListPickerDataClassObject.DrawerListObject;
        }
```

Comment: Where exactly do you call this `try {...}`?

Comment: @Justin, I added the full code of  DrawerLayout.cs

Comment: Where is `InitializeDrawerLayout` called?

Comment: I call InitializeDrawerLayout in my page, please refer edit above.

Comment: That's what I need to know... where exactly you can `InitializeDrawerLayout` on your *page*... This method is not referenced anywhere in your code.

Comment: I call it in: this.Loaded += PageConstructor_Loaded; Can you please look at my EDIT2 of question above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72201/discussion-between-atif-shabeer-and-justin-xl).